# Character of the irreducible representation $ψ^λ$ : $S_4$ → $Aut_C(S^λ)$

Tags: modules, representation-theory, characters, automorphism-group, young-tableaux

I am struggling with these exercise from group representations and would really appreciate some steps to take or sources with similar exercises.

The task is to compute the character of the irreducible representation
$ψ^λ$
: $S_4$ → $Aut_C(S^λ)$ for each λ $\vdash 4$.

And then verify that $ψ^λ$ when expressed in the matrix form with respect to the standard basis is defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ (matrices have integral coefficients).

DEFINITION: A partition of $n$ (denoted λ $\vdash n$) (is a tuple $λ = (λ_1, λ_2, . . . , λ_l)$ is a tuple for which $λ_1 ≥ λ_2 ≥ · · · ≥ λ_l ≥ 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{l} \lambda_i = 1$.

This fact may also be useful: if n ∈ N, λ $\vdash$ n, then the Specht module $S^λ$ has a basis consisting
exactly of all polytabloids associated to standard tableaux.

Comment: Are you familiar with how the permutations from $S_4$ act on those basis elements? If so, then I don't know what's holding you back? Mind you, while I have heard of Specht modules, I could not recall the definition/action. I would construct the character table of this group using less theory, but that's been done in many places. See the right margin for a link to a local resource  :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you, yes the character table part is not that difficult, actually I am struggling more with the second part - proving that the $\ψ_λ$ is defined over Z.